# Custom Preference Center - Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm looking into creating a custom preference/subscription center for my client.  They are using Salesforce as their CRM system so all subscriber information will reside in that database.  Can we just create a simple Sites page to manage subscription info directly in SFDC or do we have to push the data into ET as well?

Answer (score 2):

We do this frequently. You don't necessarily need to store this data in Data Extensions.

You would create a new page in CloudPages or Microsites and retrieve or update the Sales Cloud record directly using AMPscript. Here are the key AMPscript functions that you would need to use:

1. Pass the Salesforce Account or Contact Id to the page as a request parameter and then use the [RequestParameter()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/sites/RequestParameter.html) function to retrieve this for use in subsequent functions.
2. Use the [RetrieveSalesforceObjects()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/salesforce/RetrieveSalesforceObjects.html) function to retrieve fields for the Salesforce Account/Contact Id retrieved from the request parameter to pre-populate your form with the values.
3. Use the [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/salesforce/UpdateSingleSalesforceObject.html) to update the record in the Salesforce object with the form data the form is posted.

Here's some sample AMPscript code to retrieve values from a Salesforce Object:

```
<script runat=server language=ampscript>

var @Id, @retrievePersonAccountRecord, @limitRow, @mobileNumber, @dateofBirth, @birthDay, @birthMonth, @birthYear, @hobby

set @Id = RequestParameter('id')

set @retrievePersonAccountRecord = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Account','PersonMobilePhone, Date_of_Birth__c, Interests__c','Id', '=', @Id)
set @limitRow = Row(@retrievePersonAccountRecord, 1)
set @mobileNumber = Field(@limitRow, "PersonMobilePhone")
set @dateofBirth = Field(@limitRow, "Date_of_Birth__c")
set @birthDay = Field(@limitRow, Substring(@dateofBirth,9,2))
set @birthMonth = Field(@limitRow, Substring(@dateofBirth,6,2))
set @birthYear = Field(@limitRow, Substring(@dateofBirth,0,4))
set @hobby = Field(@limitRow, "Interests__c")
</script>
```

You can then use inline AMPscript to populate the fields. For example, `%%=v(@mobileNumber)=%%`